# Express.js Stormpath PostRegistrationHandler

Tags: stormpath

The Stormpath [documentation](http://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/product.html) 
says nothing about modifying user attributes in the PostRegistrationHandler, and I need to be able to do this.

After creating a user, I want to give it a random string as a property. This random string will be a key into my separate Mongo Database. In my app.js, I have:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {

postRegistrationHandler: function(account, res, next) {

// theoretically, this will give a user object a new property, 'mongo_id'
// which will be used to retrieve user info out of MONGOOOO
account.customData["mongo_id"] = "54aabc1c79f3e058eedcd2a7"; // <- this is the thing I'm trying to add

console.log("RESPNSE:\n"+res);  

account.save(); // I know I'm using 'account', instead of user, but the documentation uses account. I don't know how to do this any other way
next();
console.log('User:\n', account, '\njust registered!');
},

apiKeyId: '~/.stormpath.apiKey.properties',
//apiKeySecret: 'xxx',
application: ~removed~,
secretKey: ~removed~,
redirectUrl: '/dashboard',
enableAutoLogin: true

}));
```

I don't know how to my console.log line DOES print out customData with the mongo_id attribute. When I try to access it later with req.user.customData['mongo_id'], it isn't there. Account and req.user must be different. How can I save the user?

Comment: Question: are you using the 'expandCustomData' option for the library?

Comment: I am not using expandCustomData

Comment: Can you try adding that option?  I suspect that it may be required in order to work with custom data in the post registration handler

Comment: That's helpful, but it's still not saving. My data is still not saving after the post registration handler.

Comment: Well, I'll put it a different way. The data is saving in my post registration handler, but then it isn't available when I try to get the same user data inside a route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of the library mentioned above, so I think this will help a bit.

I've modified your code to work properly =)

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  postRegistrationHandler: function(account, res, next) {
    // The postRegistrationHandler is a special function that returns the account
    // object AS-IS. This means that you need to first make the account.customData stuff
    // available using account.getCustomData as described here:
    // http://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/api/account#getCustomData
    account.getCustomData(function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      } else {
        data.mongo_id = '54aabc1c79f3e058eedcd2a7';
        data.save();
        next();
      }
    });
  },
  apiKeyId: 'xxx',
  apiKeySecret: 'xxx',
  application: ~removed~,
  secretKey: ~removed~,
  redirectUrl: '/dashboard',
  enableAutoLogin: true,
  expandCustomData: true,  // this option makes req.user.customData available by default
                           // everywhere EXCEPT the postRegistrationHandler
}));
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by rdegges is not entirely correct.

The call to `next()` must be invoked only after the customData finished saving, not right away, so it has to be the callback in `data.save()`.

Also, apparently the `postRegistrationHandler` parameters have changed since to `account, req, res, next`.

Here is a currently working solution:

```
postRegistrationHandler: function(account, req, res, next) {
    account.getCustomData(function(err, data) {
        if (err)
            return next(err);

        data.mongo_id = '54aabc1c79f3e058eedcd2a7';
        data.save(next);
    });
},
```